# If I wanted to simulate keypresses over a phone line, could I just play dial tones?

Tags: audio, telephone

I'm trying to put together an API that deals with the annoyance of minutes of pressing keys to connect with a person. "For spanish, press 4. For billing, press 1. For..."

Unfortunately, it would seem most programmable phone services won't do dial tones. But many will play mp3's for hold music. If I just made an MP3 containing the desired dial tone and played it over the line, would the other end register that as a keypress? How accurate would it have to be?

Comment: How will it know which options to select?

Comment: @IanBland Natural language processing. This is a code project to see if, at least most of the time, some code can get me past the initial hassle and then call me once it connects to a person.

Comment: I think you want to generate DTMF tones, as produced by a telephone keypad, not the "dial tone" that the telephone company uses to indicate that you can dial your number.

Comment: generating the DTMF dial tones is trivial with tools like [dtmf-dial](https://github.com/TJNII/dtmfdial): `dial 123 | aplay -`. it will be harder to connect your soundcard to the phone

Answer (score 2):

DTMF touchtones follow this table: -

[image]

In other words there are two tones produced hence, any DTMF/touchtone decoder is looking for two simultaneous tones. It is unlikely that you will trigger any false detection if any relevant tone produced by your dial-tone doesn't coincide.

If you look at the data sheet of the MT8870 touchtone decoder you will get some idea where you can pitch your dialtone: -

[image]

Any tone under 500 Hz will not stand a chance of being detected correctly even if two tones were generated with one being spot on a detectable frequency.

Of course there's no guarantee that an MT8870 is being used but it gives you some confidence in choosing a single tone below 500 Hz.

Comment: How close do you have to be?

Comment: Well a dtmf decoder can distinguish between 770 Hz and 697 Hz (top two rows) so I guess you shouldn't be closer than half this distance but, if you check up on dial tones used in the world it is usually sub 300 Hz.

Comment: The real question is if you're maybe 10Hz off will it just reject the input, treating it as other audio

Comment: Remember you have to generate both tones simultaneously for a touch tone detector to work hence why dtmf means dual-tone-multi-frequency. See the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a call to another phone that has a high quality recording capablity. Record all sounds for 0...9, * and #. Beware any disturbing handling and ambient sounds. Leave also some space between the sounds for a noise print. You gonna need it in the audio editor to clean off all stationary background noise (=hiss, hum).

The DTMF system is designed to tolerate some distortion and frequency shift, so your recording should be fine at least when noise cleaned (=unhissed) and filtered to be free from off-DTMF frequency band components.

Clip the recording as separate files for each sound.

**About the question in the title**: Yes, the automatic routing machines must handle also landline calls that still have DTMF sounds for pressings.

**Offtopic**: What a great idea!

**A hint:** Add a possiblity to easily hear, maybe a little delayed, but from the very beginning, what is answered if there isn't any "press 1 for... " sequence or wait-music, but a proper human that wants to serve you.

Music and the polished machine talks like "you're still in the queue" should be detected quite easily if you already have some serious feature extraction software available.

The wanted DTMF sound sequences could be preinstalled for most common targets and new ones could be saved as you go.

Much artificial intelligence-like work, but still a great idea!